# webpack eval-source-map makes chrome breakpoint not working

Tags: google-chrome, webpack, source-maps

I 'm trying to use `eval-source-map` instead of `source-map` because doc says it should be faster to build bundles.

But if I use `eval-source-map`, breakpoints in chrome doesn't get hit.

I've googled and it doesn't seem `eval-source-map` breaks breakpoint functionality.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue with `eval-source-map`, so I finally switch back to `source-map`.

However, I do find two approaches to make `eval-source-map` work, quite dirty though.

1. Insert a `debugger` in the JS file you are working on. Open **DevTools** before you visit the page, then the `debugger` will bring you to the right place, add your break points and they should work now.
2. Or insert `console.log('here is it')` instead of `debugger`. Then open **DevTools** -> **Console**, on the right end of the line, a link will bring you to the place where `console.log` fires. Add your break points and they should also work.